# What is opt-cmd-] bound to and how can I switch this off?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, alert

In my newish Mojave install on an iMac I experience some odd behaviour:

> <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> plays the alert sound even if it is bound to an action in a keyboard shortcut tool like [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)

And it is only <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>, other key combinations which (to my knowledge) are not bound to anything. E.g <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> doesn't make any sound.

Also this behavior only seems to happen in one (my main) user account (other accounts - whether admin accounts or not) do not have this problem.

I cannot attribute this to any main application or menu bar app. (And I have quite a few of them!) How did I check?: One-by-one I quit all main apps and then all menu bar apps - still <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> plays the alert sound.

How can I find out what causes this alert tone?  How can I find out which app/tool/daemon binds to <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>?

---

***Notes***:

I care about this because I usually have on <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> a particular Keyboard Maestro macro running. This still works - but *additionally* this unexpected alert sound plays on the shortcut. (And the sound happens even if I have Keyboard Maestro completely quit.)

Comment: Any menu bar item blinks when you press that ?

Comment: @ankii No. The beep even happens when I quit all menu bar apps. %-/

Comment: Is it the same sound that happens when you hit cmd + w 5-6 times on Finder ? If so, it's an indicator of nothing happening. like an 404 error.

Comment: Yes, same sound: The alert sound you can set in the System Preferences. I understand that it is the Error/Nothing happens indicator - but what is causing it? How can i find out? See my update in the question for details why i care.

Comment: Can you boot to Safe Mode (hold `Shift` while booting).  Does the sound still play?

Comment: @Allan Thx for the hint. Will try it today and report back here.

Comment: Also, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387057/119271) for a tool to help you find it.  There's two options a paid utility with a free trial and a completely free utility - both can help you track it down.

Comment: Also, since you don't have the issue in other accounts and you don't see anything in Login Items, use the following command and past the output to to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) (or similar) and link back to your question.  This way we can see what's getting loaded.  `launchctl list`

Comment: @Allan First to the safe boot: No sound ever, but screen flash (i.e. "visible" sound). Same behaviour overall though: `⌘⌥]` generates the screen flash even if bound in Keyboard Maestro, while e.g. `⌘⌥[` does not do so.

Comment: @Allan I use KeyCue everyday. It's great! It shows only the Keyboard Maestro shortcut - which does *not* trigger the beep.

Comment: Try removing (or disabling) from KM while in Safe Mode.  Does the screen still flash? By default, nothing should happen as they're not mapped.

Comment: @Allan screen flashes on `⌥⌘]` and `⌥⌘[` in Safe mode when I have quit the KM engine.

Comment: I forgot to ask earlier, what tool was the shortcut bound to in a Keyboard Maestro

Comment: @Allan It just calls a [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/) window move command - and the Moom command definitely does *not* create the beep!

Comment: I’m wondering if more than one app has that mapping, thus the alarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcut Detective from [Irradiated Software's labs page](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) should tell you exactly what is picking up this keypress.

> ShortcutDetective detects which app receives a keyboard shortcut (hotkey).

Comment: This is some neat software and thanks for the link! But t as stated on their page and in the link of my comment - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387057/119271 - not all shortcuts can be detected if the app doesn't register it.

Comment: Thanks @John Noble. Will check it out today and report back.

Comment: ShortcutDetective found it! It was [Copied](https://copied.app/) which hogged the shortcut. But because I run it as a Menu-Bar-only app the shortcut did show up in KeyCue! ShortcutDetective is a great tip!

Answer (score 1):

I would go into system preferences > keyboard > shortcuts, and browse through all of the keyboard shortcuts and see if any have `⌘⌥]`as they’re keybind. you could also open Automator, and press the record button, press `⌘⌥]` and then click stop recording and see what it says that you did.

Comment: Good suggestion. However none of the shortcuts in the System preferences has `⌘⌥]` assigned to it.

Comment: Also recording the key stroke in Automator gives me back an *empty* **Watch Me Do** action. (However recording another keystroke e.g. `⌘⌥[` fives me a **Watch Me Do** action with the "Press ⌘⌥[" event! - There's clearly something going on with `⌘⌥]`.)

Comment: It may be somewhat bound to the '⌘[' or '⌘]' go back/forward shortcuts. I'm assuming that you are an admin on your Mac. if you go to >sign out, and press '⌘⌥]'. Are you using an apple keyboard or a 3rd party one.

Comment: I use an Apple Keyboard. What do you mean with "*if you go to >sign out, and press '⌘⌥]'*"? - I don't understand.

Comment: @halloleo the  menu at the side of the menu bar
sorry I forgot to put menu

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the 'bonk' sound to stop then go to System Preferences > Sound and move the Alert Volume slider to the left. In this case you might miss out on other alerts mac tries to tell you.

Comment: This is not really a fix for me: I need to the Alarm sound for audible feedback in many other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't apply to your situation with macOS Mojave, but might be helpful for future viewers.

---

If you're using macOS Catalina (10.15) or newer and you're wondering about applications that might be intercepting specific key combinations, look at the list of applications that have the **Input Monitoring** permission granted in Security & Privacy settings.

That, combined with the [standard keyboard shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387226/18101), should account for all the different ways that global hotkey keyboard shortcuts can be installed.