# I have to use the FN key for shortcuts to work

Tags: keyboard

So I have an issue where I use well-known shortcuts like <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (save) or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (find) and they don't work. However if I introduce the <kbd>fn</kbd> key, they start working (i.e. <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>).

Regular <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> work.

I also have the setting in *System preferences → Keyboard* "use F1, F2, etc. as standard functions" selected.

I can't figure out how the <kbd>fn</kbd> seems to be toggled the wrong way (up when it should be down and down when it is up) for shortcuts or where to look next.

This is happening on the laptop keyboard and my Magic keyboard attached via Bluetooth.

***Machine specs***

- macOS Catalina 10.15.4
- Mac Pro 2017 (13" with Touch Bar)

Comment: In which version of macOS is this happening? Can you pls include in your post which Mac (and keyboard if applicable) model you are using?

Comment: Can you make sure that the Fn key isn’t already pressed somehow. Check on any online virtual keyboard.

Comment: Do the `Fn` keys work as expected?  Did you remap any keys by chance?  See the apps in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387057/119271) to see what shortcuts are currently bound.

Comment: So I have checked the bound shortcuts and they are as expected.  I am also using the macOS keyboard viewer to see if any key is being held down, which there is none.  Interestingly the keyboard shows the F1.. F12 Keys by default and the tough bar has it's controls.