# Certain key combinations (involving CMD) don't work

Tags: mac, keyboard, catalina, hardware

My left command key is not working for certain key combinations, but it works fine by itself, and in some other combinations. e.g.

Fails:

- left-cmd + tab (switch apps)
- left-cmd + w (close window/tab)

Succeeds:

- left-cmd + r (refresh)
- left-cmd + s (save)
- left-cmd + /* anything else I've tried */

Also Succeeds:

- right-cmd + tab
- right-cmd + w
- right-cmd + /* anything else I've tried */

I've tried:

- zap PRAM: still fails
- restart: fails
- safe mode: still fails
- pulling my hair out:
  still fails

Could this be a keyboard hardward problem?

Comment: You probably have some conflicting keybinding somewhere.  Start with the software in this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387057/119271 and see if you can see what's trapping the keys

Comment: @Allan That was the prime suspect, but failing in Safe Mode should have removed that possibility.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If it's an Apple product, it's not going to disable it.  Your custom keyboard shortcuts, text replacements, etc. are still present in Safe Mode.